# Jmeter doesn't work in other environment though it works local

Tags: logging, jmeter

Hi I had configure a .jmx to work with a thread group that does a simple http request.

It works perfectly locally, but when I upload the .jmx to another server in amazon it doesn't work.

Differences between local machine and ec2 server:
**local:**

is ubuntu when jmeter was installed
   as sudo apt-get install jmeter. And
   the version is **2.3.4**.

the jmeter.log is something like this:

```
2010/09/09 11:17:05 INFO  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to es_AR 
2010/09/09 11:17:05 WARN  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Could not find resources for 'es_AR', using 'es' 
2010/09/09 11:17:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2009 The Apache Software Foundation 
2010/09/09 11:17:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Version 2.3.4 
2010/09/09 11:17:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.6.0_18 
2010/09/09 11:17:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.vm.name=OpenJDK Server VM 
2010/09/09 11:17:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.name=Linux 
2010/09/09 11:17:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.arch=i386 
2010/09/09 11:17:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.version=2.6.32-24-generic 
2010/09/09 11:17:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: file.encoding=UTF-8 
2010/09/09 11:17:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Default Locale=español (Argentina) 
2010/09/09 11:17:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=español (Argentina) 
2010/09/09 11:17:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeterHome=/usr/share/jmeter 
2010/09/09 11:17:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: user.dir  =/home/dnoseda/Dropbox/jmeter 
2010/09/09 11:17:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: PWD       =/home/dnoseda/Dropbox/jmeter 
2010/09/09 11:17:05 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: IP: 127.0.1.1 Name: ml FullName: ml 
2010/09/09 11:17:06 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler: readRespo
```

and keep going.

**Server:**

the jmeter was download and unzipped. And the version is **Version 2.3.4**

the log is something like this:

```
2010/09/09 11:31:47 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: jmeterthread.startearlier=true (see jmeter.properties) 
2010/09/09 11:31:47 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Running PostProcessors in forward order 
2010/09/09 11:31:47 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Usuarios 1-1 
2010/09/09 11:31:47 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All threads have been started 
2010/09/09 11:31:47 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Usuarios 1-2 
2010/09/09 11:31:47 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Usuarios 1-3 
2010/09/09 11:31:47 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Usuarios 1-4 
2010/09/09 11:31:47 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.parser.HtmlParserHTMLParser: Using htmlparser version: 2.0 (Release Build Sep 17, 2006) 
2010/09/09 11:31:47 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.parser.HTMLParser: Created org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.HtmlParserHTMLParser 
2010/09/09 11:31:47 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Usuarios 1-5
```

And stops there.

Can you give any pointer? Maybe some way of debug the jmeter in the ec2 server?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the proper java sdk version running on the server?

I haven't setup Jmeter to run from a server before, but the article below is how to get Jakarta JMeter up and running on a fresh Ubuntu 6.06 Server (Dapper Drake) install:

http://www.das-werkstatt.com/forum/werkstatt/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=396